# Opening a pop up window automatically on the date mentioned in the function

Tags: html, javascript, pop-up

I want it to remain open from the specified date onwards. This is the code I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function newPopup(url) {
  popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','...');
}

var date = new Date();
var formatedDate = date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getFullYear();

if (formatedDate == "27/010/2018 ") {
   newPopup("http://example.com");
}
```

How to improve it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.